# Change string to specific integer while parsing from x.dat to x.csv?

Tags: python

I have data in x.dat as follows:

```
1::F::1::10::48067
2::M::56::16::70072
3::M::25::15::55117
```

I want to convert to x.csv with the conversion of M into 1 and F into 2, thus the new result in csv is:

```
1,2,1,10,48067
2,1,56,16,70072
3,1,25,15,55117
```

How to do that in Python?

Comment: start with reading and writing files (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html). [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module may help. If you get stuck [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52416118/edit) and update your question.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? It matters.

Comment: You can read the file (line by line) and replace what you want. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: @martineau Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `replace` function:**

```
with open("x.csv", "w") as fw:
    with open("x.dat", "r") as fr:
        for line in fr:
            new_line = line.replace("::", ",").replace("F", "2").replace("M", "1")
            fw.write(new_line)
```

**Using `re` module:**

```
import re

rep = {
    "F": "2",
    "M": "1",
    "::": ",",
}
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
with open("x.csv", "w") as fw:
    with open("x.dat", "r") as fr:
        for line in fr:
            new_line = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], line)
            fw.write(new_line)
```

Comment: If I want to change specific value, e.g, '0' value only to '0.000' in specific column, what should I do? If I use your method above, it will change all '0's in all columns including value '110', not specific '0' only.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
with open("x.dat") as f:
    with open("x.csv", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            m= line.split("::")
            if(m[1]=='M'):
                m[1]=1
            else:
                m[1]=2
            for ele in m:
                f1.write(str(ele)+',')
```